# Horizontal number picker with encircled selected item

Tags: android, android-number-picker

IS there a library I can use to implement a horizontally-scrolling number picker such as the one shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it custom as per requirement.

```
<com.wefika.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker
        xmlns:picker="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.wefika.horizontalpicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
        android:ellipsize="none | start | middle | end | marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="-1"
        picker:values="@array/values"
        picker:dividerSize="@dimen/itemPadding"
        picker:sideItems="@integer/sideItems" />
```

Follow [this](https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker)